# FTPS Upload in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ftps

I'm in the process of learning Powershell, and am working on a little script that will upload a group of files to an FTPS server nightly. The files are located on a network share in a sub-directory containing the date in the name. The files themselves will all begin with the same string, let's say "JONES_". I have this script working for FTP, but I don't quite get what I need to do to get it to work for FTPS:

```
# Set yesterday's date (since uploads will happen at 2am)
$YDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')

#Create Log File
$Logfile = "C:\powershell\$YDate.log"
Function LogWrite
{
    Param ([string]$logstring)

    Add-Content $Logfile -value $logstring
}


# Find Directory w/ Yesterday's Date in name
$YesterdayFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\network\storage\location" | Where-Object {$_.FullName.contains($YDate)}


If ($YesterdayFolder) {

    #we specify the directory where all files that we want to upload are contained 
    $Dir= $YesterdayFolder
    #ftp server
    $ftp = "ftp://ftps.site.com"
    $user = "USERNAME"
    $pass = "PASSWORD"

    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)


$FilesToUpload = Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path $YesterdayFolder.FullName "Report") | Where-Object {$_.Name.StartsWith("JONES","CurrentCultureIgnoreCase")}
foreach($item in ($FilesToUpload))
    { 
        LogWrite "Uploading file:  $YesterdayFolder\Report\$item"
        $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
        $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName)  
    }
    } Else {
        LogWrite "No files to upload"
    }
```

I'd rather not have to deal with a 3rd party software solution, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using psftp didn't work for me. I couldn't get it to connect to the FTP over SSL. I ended up (reluctantly?) using WinSCP with this code:

```
$PutCommand = '& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /command "open ftp://USER:PASS@ftps.hostname.com:21/directory/ -explicitssl" "put """"' + $Item.FullName + '""""" "exit"' 
Invoke-Expression $PutCommand
```

In the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would consider this as "3rd party software" or not, but you can run [PSFTP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) from within Powershell.  Here is an example of how you could do that ([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1c9e20fd-19d7-41b4-8edb-d6673ab35bec/sftp-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)):

```
$outfile=$YesterdayFolder"\Report\"$item.Name
"rm $outfile`nput $outfile`nbye" | out-file batch.psftp -force -Encoding ASCII

$user = "USERNAME"
$pass = "PASSWORD"

&.\psftp.exe  -l $user -pw $pass  $ftp -b batch.psftp -be
```

Comment: I assume the line:
`&.\psftp.exe  -l $user -pw $pass  $ftp -b batch.psftp -be`

replaces:
    `$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)`

?

Comment: I think it replaces several lines in the code you presented.  Essentially, it runs psftp, passing in the username, password, and list of commands to be run, meaning that one line of code handles the login and upload of the file in question.  That removes 3 lines of code by my count, but you may choose to implement it as it suits you.